# How to strip a string from all chars besides for specific ones?

Tags: java, string

I have a string that I must filter, in some scenarios to only contain the characters 'a' through 'f' or the digits '0' through '9' and in other scenarios, just the digits '1' through '9'.

Since i am not looking to strip any specific chars, rather to only preserve specific chars, using a loop to go through the every character in unicode save those i'd like to preserve would seem to be slight overkill.

Here's the signature of the method i'm looking to write:

```
String stripExtras(CharSequence input, CharSequence legalChars){
}
```

And I'd use it like in this example:

```
String example = "aeiou456";
String output = stripExtras(example,"abcdef0123456789");
System.out.println(output);
```

where the output should be `ae456`.

Iv'e seen a method in `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` called `containsOnly` that returns a boolean  value representing if the input contains the specified chars, but the source is a bit beyond my grasp.

How do I go about filtering a string to allow only specific characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is implementation that works on Java 1.5 and later.

```java
static String stripExtras(CharSequence input, CharSequence legalChars) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char ch = input.charAt(i);
        if (contains(legalChars, input.charAt(i)))
            output.append(ch);
    }
    return output.toString();
}
static boolean contains(CharSequence str, char ch) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        if (str.charAt(i) == ch)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

*Test*

```java
String example = "aeiou456";
String output = stripExtras(example,"abcdef0123456789");
System.out.println(output);
```

*Output*

```
ae456
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
static String stripExtras(CharSequence input, CharSequence legalChars){
    return input.toString().replaceAll("[^" + legalChars + "]", "");
}
```

But you can not specify special characters ("]", "-", ...) as `legalChars`.

if you mind this limitation.

```
static String stripExtras(CharSequence input, CharSequence legalChars){
    Set<Integer> regalSet = legalChars.codePoints().boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new HashSet<>(legalChars.length())));
    return input.codePoints()
        .filter(regalSet::contains)
        .collect(StringBuilder::new,
            (sb, cp) -> sb.appendCodePoint(cp),
            StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Works with ASCII or Unicode characters.

```
String example = "aeiou456";
String output = stripExtras(example, "abcdef0123456789");
System.out.println(output);

static String stripExtras(CharSequence input,
        CharSequence legalChars) {
        return input.codePoints()
                .filter(a -> legalChars.toString().indexOf(a) >= 0)
                .mapToObj(Character::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
}
```

Prints

```
ae456
```